# Transferring Java files into Kotlin in Android Studio

Tags: java, android, kotlin

With the Android 3.0 release, I noticed that it now supports Kotlin natively now. I also saw that there is a Java to Kotlin "converter" if you will that is available. I have a medium sized project on Android Studio that I've been working on with Java and I was wondering if it would be wise to convert everything into Kotlin.

Is Kotlin worth converting all my files into the language?

Comment: No. -----------

Comment: It pretty much never makes sense to change languages mid project.  Consider it for your next one.  If this is a professional project it makes even less sense-  there's a large pool of Java programmers, and a tiny one of Kotlin

Comment: If you do decide to convert to Kotlin, [this](https://medium.com/google-developers/lessons-learned-while-converting-to-kotlin-with-android-studio-f0a3cb41669) might help.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

No.  Kotlin is 100% interop with Java (Kotlin code can call Java code and Java code can call Kotlin code).  You may have an objective to eventually transition to Kotlin completely, but you shouldn't use the Kotlin converter and assume everything works completely out of the box.  The Kotlin converter doesn't make idiomatic Kotlin, plus you will still have a lot of !! variables where you will have to determine when and where those variables can be nullable or not.  I would recommend any time you add a new feature, use Kotlin.  Any time you refactor any of your Java classes, try and convert them over to Kotlin then.  Java will continue to be supported on Android for a long time so there is no rush for you to transition.  Also, if the Java code isn't broken and you aren't needing to make changes to it, why bother giving yourself more work?  What benefit would you get from converting Java code that you don't touch for long periods of time over to Kotlin?

Answer (score 3):

## Is it worth converting all my code straight away

Normally no, Kotlin and Java have interop, so you can keep your old code and just write the bits you want in Kotlin in Kotlin. The Java and Kotlin code can call each other easily.

## Should I just use the convertor

No, the converter is good, but not perfect, so you will need to manually edit it afterwards to fix any errors.

## Is Kotlin worth writing in for new code

I would say yes, I think the benefits do outweigh the cost of learning it. Some of these benefits are:

- Null Safety

  - Less null pointers
- Smart Casting

  - You rarely need to cast and risk errors
- When statements

  - Cleans up long groups of if statements
- Default arguments

  - Cleans up overloads
- The elvis operator

  - Allows for working with code that may return null

There are a few reasons it may not be worth using for your project though:

- If you are in a team all members would need to know Kotlin
- Your build system may only support Java
- You may need to use a verification system that only supports Java